# Font name of windows taskbar

Tags: windows-7, fonts, taskbar

Windows 7: I downloaded a program to give me a taskbar on my 2nd monitor at work. The font on that second taskbar is off. I would like to try and change it to match the main taskbar. What is the font of the taskbar/how do you check? I do have an option to specify a new font.

[image: Font Comparison]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Windows 7 default fonts it should be the "Segoe UI" font. It may be Bolded, and/or be using the "Segoe UI Semibold" variant.

Comment: That's what it's set to. I have no idea why it looks different then.

Comment: Well, I still answered your question. ;)  If you switch which monitor is the primary, does the "fatter" font follow the native taskbar, or does it stay on the same monitor? I'm wondering if it's just different looking due to monitor resolution differences.

Comment: 2x same monitor. Stays same where ever it travels.

Comment: Hmmm, if you change the font used on the 3rd party software to use the "Segoe UI Semibold" font, does it look the same? As an aside/alternative, I use DisplayFusion for my multi-monitor taskbars, and the fonts look the same as the native Taskbar on my systems.

Comment: Looks the same.